# How would I approach solving this Little Oh problem?

Tags: functions, algorithms, asymptotics

**$2n + 10 \in o(n^2)$.**

My understanding of Little Oh is that for any positive constant $c$, there exists a constant $n_0 > 0$ such that $f(n) \leq c\cdot g(n)$ for all $n > n_0$.

How I think I should do it is:

Plug the functions in as:

- $2n+10 \leq cn^2$

and try to solve for n. But I get stuck here:

- $(2n+10)/n^2 \leq c$
- $2/n + 10/n^2 \leq c $

EDIT:
An answer in my notes is $n$ > $n_0$ > $(20/c)$^(1/2) and $4/c$. I have no idea how to arrive at that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"But I get stuck here: $2/n + 10/n^2 \leq c.$ An answer in my notes is $n>n_0>(20/c)^{1/2}$ and $4/c$. I have no idea how to arrive at that answer."

You were on the right track. A (not necessary but) sufficient condition for
$$2/n + 10/n^2 \leq c$$
is to have both
$$2/n\leq c/2\quad\text{and}\quad10/n^2 \leq c/2,$$
i.e. both
$$n\ge4/c\quad\text{and}\quad n^2\ge20/c,$$
which is equivalent to$$n\ge\max(4/c,(20/c)^{1/2}).$$

Answer (score 1):

You seem to ask two different questions, so I'll just answer the question you were trying to solve.

Prove that $2n+10 \in o(n^2)$. I'll start as you did, let $c> 0$, then

$$2n+10<cn^2 \iff \frac{2n+10}{n^2}\leq c \iff \frac{2}{n}+ \frac{10}{n^2}\leq c$$

*Here please observe that you had a mistake in the last implication, but also observe that you really need the if and only if in each step.*

Thus, to prove the claim we need to show that for every $c>0$, there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n_0>n$ we have $\frac{2}{n} + \frac{10}{n^2}\leq c$. To do this either use the fact that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2}{n} + \frac{10}{n^2} = 0.$

Comment: Sorry, I tried to come up with a similar question to the one I'm trying to figure out so that I could generalize a solution to this type of question, but I completely confused myself and put in my attempt for the original.

So an appropriate point for n0 where c*g(n) becomes greater than f(n) would be the limit of 2/n as n approaches infinity + the limit of 10/n^2 as n approaches infinity? Which means, n0 would be 0 and n any number greater than 0?

Comment: No worries. Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{2}{n}+\frac{10}{n^2}=0$ you know that for every $c>0$ there exists some $n_0$ so that for all $n>n_0$ we have $\frac{2}{n}+\frac{10}{n^2}<c$, which is what you need.